# angularjs using directive inside another directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I am trying to create a tab within a directive template, the tab works but I don't know how to render other directives when appropriate tab is selected.

Here is the code for my tabs directive.

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('q2022Tabs', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                max: '=',
                label: '='
            },
            require: "q2022PieRadarChart" + "q2022RadarChart", 
            template: `
            <form name="outerForm" class="tab-form-demo">
    <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="Radar Chart">
        (content tab)
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="2" heading="Pie Radar Chart">
        (content tab 2)
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </form>
        `
        };
    }])
    .controller('ExController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {


    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

First I updated the template code as follows:

```
template: '<div class="views">' +
          '    <div class="view-wrapper" ng-repeat="view in views">' +
          '        <div view="{{view.dir}}"></div>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '</div>',
```

Note that I created a new 'view' directive. Next the view directive definition as follows:

```
app.directive('view', ['$compile', function (compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            view: '@'
        },
        replace: true,   
        template: '<div class="view"></div>',

        controller: ['$scope', function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('view', function (value) {
                scope.buildView(value);
            });
        }],

        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

            scope.buildView = function (viewName) {
                var view = compile('<div ' + viewName + '></div>')(scope);
                elm.append(view);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

So essentially, the view.dir variable is passed as an attribute to the 'view' directive, which then watches it's value and compiles a template with the directive in it.

Comment: where do I add the tab name and the directive files?